# Determine K so that the function can serve as a joint probability function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to find k such that

$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
kx(x-y),  & \text{if 0<$x$<1, -$x$<$y$<$x$} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$

can serve as a joint probability density.
I understand that I have to plug in values of $x$ and $y$, under the conditions given, and sum everything up and equal it to $1$. The problem I'm having is with the restrictions. I can plug in an infinite numbers of $X$ and $Y$ under that condition. I just don't know what to do. Any hint or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: **Read** your book where it tells you about joint probability **density** functions, not where it tells you about joint probability **mass** functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $f(x,y)$ to be a pdf, you need the integration of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be $1$. In other words,
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)\, dy\,dx = \int_0^1 \int_{-x}^x kx(x-y)\,dy\,dx = 1$$
Note that the second integral is over the region $\{ 0 < x < 1, -x < y < x \}$ since $f$ is $0$ everywhere else. Evaluating the integral should give you a value for $k$.